# Is there any good userscript for stackoverflow text editor?

Tags: text-editor, stack-exchange

The most uncomfortable thing I feel with stackoverflow  is this text editor :

[image]

If I want to add code under a numbered list, I need 8 space indent.

For example:

1. Test code

   ```
   hello world!
   ```

But this editor not support `tab` key . Just not feel good in my opinion.

So I wonder if there are some good userscript

Comment: Unfortunately only works for the 4-space indention: try `Ctrl`+`K` with the code text highlighted. First press indents, second removes indention.

Comment: @ Izzy♦ Yeah, so I am looking for a userscript which can enhance this editor,  not found on https://greasyfork.org/en

Comment: Understood. Just wanted to offer a partial solution until a final one turns up. Might also be worth a feature request to stack devs :)

Comment: It is not the StackOverflow editor, but, rather, the Stack**Exchange** editor and, as such, you will probably get most help at https://meta.stackexchange.com/